# Counterexample: Topologize union of topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology

Here is the question.

Q: Let $X$ be a **set** which is the union of the topological spaces $\{X_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in I}$. Then, can we always give topology on $X$ of which each $X_{\alpha}$ is a subspace?

The Exercise 1(b) of Section37 in Munkres' "Elements of Algebraic Topology" tells that above claim is not true and requires readers to find a counterexample. He also gives following hints.

HINT: Let $A,B$ and $C$ be three disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, each of which is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $A,B,X_1=\mathbb{R}-A$ and $X_2=\mathbb{R}-B$ be topologized as subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$; Let $X_3=A\cup B$ be topologized as the topological sum of $A$ and $B$. Let $X=X_1\cup X_2 \cup X_3$. Compute $\bar{A}$.

So, I followed above hint. Let $A=\mathbb{Q},B=\sqrt{2}+\mathbb{Q}$ and $C=\sqrt{3}+\mathbb{Q}$. And proved that $\bar{A}=X$. But from here, How can we make contradiction? I did not use the fact $X_3$ is a subspace of $X$, so probably using that fact is the key. But I don't know how to.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The set $A$ is dense in $X_2$, so $\bar A\supset X_2=\Bbb R - B$. From the other hand, the set $B$ is open in $X_3=A\cup B$,
so $B\cap\bar A=\varnothing$. Thus $\bar A=X_2$. Then the set $B=\Bbb R - X_2$ is open in $X$ and therefore in 
$X_1$, which contradicts to that the set $C$ is dense in $X_1$.

PS. But I don’t understand, why we need so complicated counterexample to the initial question, because we can simply
take as $X_1$  and $X_2$ two different topological spaces on the same set $X$.

Comment: Re the PS, presumably the $X_\alpha$ are meant to be required to be compatible on their intersections.

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that B and the closure of A are disjoint?

Comment: @Michael Since the set $B$ is open in $X_3$, there exists an open subset $B'$ of $X$ such that $B'\cap X_3=B$. Since $X_3=B\cup A$, we have $B’\cap A=\varnothing$. Since the set $B’$ is open, $B’\cap \bar A=\varnothing$, so  $B\cap\bar A=\varnothing$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thanks, by the way, 'B and the closure of A are disjoint' is enough for a contradiction, since A is dense, which means its closure is R.

Comment: @Michael The set $A$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ endowed with the usual topology, but a priori is not clear whether $A$ is dense in $\Bbb R=X$ endowed with any topology from the question.